# converting double to binary in java

Tags: java, binary, double

I am generating sequence of numbers of type double like
0.9913963644564902 
0.0341175990344773 
0.13181105852355268 
0.45773616980747556 
and I have to convert it to binary representation in java.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to binary"?  What output are you expecting for this example?

Comment: You probably want to use a DataOutputStream. Read the javadoc.

Comment: The author most probably wants the actual floating point number in binary format (infinite precision). I do not think he wants to have all fields of the IEEE 8 byte double as a binary integer.

Comment: @afk5min: But that's not something he/she can have, as most finite decimal expansions have infinite binary expansions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you. I have tried out using one of your input double value - 0.9913963644564902

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
        double d = 0.9913963644564902;
        System.out.println("0b"+Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d)));
    }
```

The output would be

```
run:
0b11111111101111101110011000010011011110010101101101100001110011
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Why would you think the author would want a binary INTEGER as a result?

Comment: Thanks it worked . will it also work for negative numbers

Comment: Yes, for -0.9913963644564902, output would be *run:
0b1011111111101111101110011000010011011110010101101101100001110011
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)*

Comment: Do you need to map the sequence numbers and binary. go for Map

Comment: Yes, ofcourse you can!